# Is there a single working OCaml IDE?

Tags: ide, ocaml

I have downloaded multiple OCaml IDE's / plugins and NONE of them work. I have no clue if I have a directory problem or if something else is at fault. I can access the OCaml console through cygwin just fine but it is not very useful for dealing with larger files. I am a total OCaml noob and have no clue how to fix my problems. I have been reading every post on OCaml here and nothing is helping. I am hoping that somebody can help me because this is very frustrating! Thanks to all who reply.

Comment: Many work, yes. Care to tell us what difficulties you're experiencing?

Comment: my first suggestion would be to ditch cygwin and run linux in a VM. All of the ide's and plugins should then work out of the box.

Comment: Here are some problems I have been experiencing with a few IDE's: Camelia - I get an error that says compiler not found, when I correct the path to the compiler and try to compile any code it stops working and terminates. NetBeans OCaml IDE - Nothing happens when I try to compile. Eclipe ODT plugin - console has no cursor and hitting the run button does nothing. Thanks for the responses. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank everybody for their help. I finally found some installation instructions for the tuareg mode in EMACS. In case anybody else is having the same problem that I was there are VERY clear instructions here

[How to install tuareg](http://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~jlc/courses/4780/installEmacsOCamlTuareg.html)

Hopefully I can now translate some stuff into OCaml that I have been working on in other languages and post some of my projects. Thanks again for all of the help.

Answer (score 8):

OCaml modes for Emacs and Vim work perfectly (and they run on MacOS and Windows, of course). I heard Geany works well as well.

I'm not saying everyone must learn Emacs and Vim; I understand that it's a kind of interface that beginners maybe don't want to get into -- and supporting other editors well for OCaml is a problem that we need to fix. But if you want reasonable support for pretty much every kind of text format out there, they're still good choices.

Finally, if you have a decent terminal / command-line (if you are on Windows that might require running a GNU/Linux virtual machine), pretty much every editor will be fine if you compile stuff by hand from the terminal (which is not particularly hard). In-Editor support will still provide you with a better experience, in particular allowing to jump right to the place in your code where the compiler says there is an error, but as a beginner you can go a long way without even that.

PS: it would be *extremely useful* if you took the time to spell out precisely what your problem with each tool was, and send that information to the respective maintainers. I think the main problem with these tools is the lack of testers. Help the future people that will try these tools by helping the maintainers fix them!

Comment: I have tried to install the tuareg mode for EMACS but I have never used EMACS before and all of my attempts at installation have been unsuccessful. I don't really understand the installation instructions and I cannot find any instructions that clearly explain to a non EMACS user how to install the tuareg mode. If anybody is willing to post some instructions that would be awesome because I have fumbled with it for too long.

Comment: @user2379958 : I believe the [OCaml for Windows installer](http://protz.github.io/ocaml-installer/) includes an option to install Emacs configured with OCaml (that uses the `caml-mode` instead of `tuareg`, but this is a detail and both work fine), and generally tries to make sure that it all works together. Have you tried this way of installing Emacs, and if so can you report on what didn't work for you, so that it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I'v recently looked at [OcaIDE](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/) for eclipse - and it seems to work.
You need perhaps set some configuration variables (paths to ocaml compiler,...), but I don't remember any quirks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Notepad++ for Windows. It is more intuitive for than Vim or Emacs for the beginners. And it has a syntax highlighting for Caml and you can assign hotkeys for compiling executing the program.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using OcaIDE. I've done some fairly large projects with it, and it's not bad. Emacs (with Tuareg mode) is also a good option. If you're having trouble with setup, I wrote a guide for OS X: http://www.princeton.edu/~crmarsh/ocaml_dev_environment/